# border left and right dissapear when using scrollable div (overflow: auto)

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

I'm trying to add border to a `tr[mar-row]`.
It's working file until the table parent have a scrollbar (`overflow: auto`)

Repro : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9s1meu?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable-basic-example.css

comment the `overflow: auto` at line 2 and the borders will be entirely visible.

Any idea to have the border and keep the parent scrollable ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `outline-offset: -2px` to move the outline in by its width. Because `outline` is drawn outside of the [elements borders](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/outline) the left and right sides are being hidden when `overflow: auto` is set — `outline` is not part of the element's actual height/width.

Alternatively, use `border` so the style is drawn as part of the height/width calculations. Though `tr.selected {border: 1px solid black}` wasn't immediately working, it does by targeting the children:

```
tr.selected td {
  border-top: 2px solid red;
  border-bottom: 2px solid red;
}
tr.selected td:first-child {
  border-left: 2px solid red;
}
tr.selected td:last-child {
  border-right: 2px solid red;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.
Now that you mention it, it seems obvious.

I think it is possible to solve the problem at the source by adding another wrapper with negative margins. But in the meantime, your solution will do very well.

I didn't even know you could apply an offset to an outline, I always used shadowss to make internal borders.